# What would be the SQL Server equivalent for a Row Constructor Comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
WHERE  (project, grant, program, department) in 
(('pj1', 'gr1', 'pg1', 'dp1'),
 ('pj3', 'gr2', 'pg1', 'dp2'),
 ('pj6', 'gr3', 'pg2', 'dp1')
)
```

What would be the equivalent of the above `Oracle` query criteria in `SQL Server`?

The intention here is to find the result for a certain particular combination of the column values.

Comment: A `VALUES` table construct and a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

- See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Use an `INNER JOIN` with a `VALUES()` table to return only matching rows:

```
SELECT
    stuff
FROM
    yourTable AS t
    INNER JOIN (
        VALUES
            ('pj1', 'gr1', 'pg1', 'dp1'),
            ('pj3', 'gr2', 'pg1', 'dp2'),
            ('pj6', 'gr3', 'pg2', 'dp1')
    ) AS v( project, grant, program, dept ) ON
        v.project = t.project
        AND
        v.grant = t.grant
        AND
        v.program = t.program
        AND
        v.dept = t.dept
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this entirely in the `where` clause using `exists`:

```
where exists (select 1
              from (values ('pj1', 'gr1', 'pg1', 'dp1'),
                           ('pj3', 'gr2', 'pg1', 'dp2'),
                           ('pj6', 'gr3', 'pg2', 'dp1')
                   ) v(project, grant, program, department)
              where v.project = t.project and
                    v.grant = t.grant and
                    v.program = t.program and
                    v.department = t.program
             )
```

`t` is the table alias for the table that contains the columns.  You might have more than one alias.